# Firebase - Get data by key or chid values - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, web, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to read the data from firebase database, and display the same in a webpage.

My database structure is as below -
[image: Image here]

If you see the image, i am able to read the "**UserData**" using the below code -

```
firebase.initializeApp(config);
var database = firebase.database(); 

var ref = database.ref('UserData');
ref.once('value', gotData1, errData);

    function gotData1(data){
    //console.log(data.val());
    var usrData = data.val();
    var keys = Object.keys(usrData);
    //console.log(keys);

    for (var i = 0; i< keys.length; i++){
        var k = keys[i];
        var id = usrData[k].AssignedID;
        var name = usrData[k].Name;

        $(document).ready(function() {
             var $formrow = '<tr><td>'+id+'</td><td>'+name+'</td></tr>';
             $('#userInfo').append($formrow);
        });
     }
    }
```

In the highlighted part of the image, you can see keys with values 196214, 196215, 196216

Now, I need to fetch the values for **"One, Count"** by matching the key values with available AssignedID.

How can i achieve the same?

Update, JSON as text -

```
{
  "app_url" : "https://app_name?ls=1&mt=8",
  "UserData" : {
    "HNpTPoCiAYMZEeVOs01ncfGBj6X2" : {
      "Name" : "Arunima Vj"
      "Email" : "asd@upp.com",
      "AssignedID" : 196214
    },
    "VXU2tdGdzZX90PJa9mpEL3zAiZo2" : {
      "Name" : "Lakshman Medicherla"
      "Email" : "asd@upp.com",
      "AssignedID" : 196215
    },
    "dFlwtqDNrja2RkOySVtW106IQP62" : {
      "Name" : "Prashanth Sripathi"
      "Email" : "asd@upp.com",
      "AssignedID" : 196216
    }
  }
  "teams" : {
    "196214" : {
      "1105" : {
        "One" : 7619,
        "count" : 24
      },
      "1379" : {
        "Two" : 7145,
        "count" : 21
      }
    },
    "196215" : {
      "1111" : {
        "One" : 7779,
        "count" : 20
      },
      "1508" : {
        "Two" : 1176,
        "count" : 21
      }
    },
    "196216" : {
      "1106" : {
        "One" : 7845,
        "count" : 22
      },
      "1509" : {
        "Two" : 1156,
        "count" : 26
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: Hi Frank, thanks for your comment. I am only working on designing and developing of he webapp, so i dont have access to the firebase app window.  

Update:
Please check, I have updated the post with JSON as text

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Please check, I have updated the post with JSON as text

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your data structure is quite nested, which makes the code more difficult to read. But this navigates the structure generically in the minimum code I could come up with:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref("/42824688");

ref.child("UserData").once('value', gotUserData);

function gotUserData(snapshot){
  snapshot.forEach(userSnapshot => {
    var k = userSnapshot.key;
    var id = userSnapshot.val().AssignedID;
    var name = userSnapshot.val().Name;
    ref.child("teams").child(id).once("value", teamsSnapshot => {
      teamsSnapshot.forEach(teamSnapshot => {
        var teamKey = teamSnapshot.key;
        teamSnapshot.forEach(teamProp => {
          var prop = teamProp.key;
          var val = teamProp.val();
          console.log(k+" "+name+" "+id+": "+teamKey+", "+prop+"="+val);
        });
      });
    });
  })
}
```

So for each user, this loads the teams data for that user and then loops over the `teamsSnapshot` to get each `teamSnapshot` and then loops over *that* to get each team property.

Working jsbin: http://jsbin.com/noziri/edit?html,js,console

Comment: Thanks Frank, this code really helps me.
Now, I want to take the values of "one", "count" in two different variables, and when I try to fetch the same using 

**var val = teamProp.val().count;** for count, "undefined" is printed to the console, any idea why is that happening?
Thanks again.